# Textarea returns empty value in PHP POST

Tags: php, html, post, textarea

I am facing problem in textarea content POST via PHP. I have a form that submits two values one in textarea and other radio button. while submitting the radio button value is posted but textarea value showed up empty.

why is this happening? Any suggestion would be appreciated..

My snippet of HTML Code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="register_form">
<h2><img class="small_image" src="images/rsz_heart.png">Describe 
Yourself<img class="small_image" src="images/heart.png"></h2>
<table id="register_table">
<tr>
<td>Describe Yourself</td>
<td>
<textarea id="description" type="textarea" name="description" rows="5" 
cols="40" class="textbox" form="register_form" required>type</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Any disability</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="disability" value="none" selected="selected">None
<input type="radio" name="disability" value="physicaldisability">Physical 
Disability
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" >
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My PHP code is

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"]))
{  
$description = $_POST["description"];
$disability = $_POST["disability"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
$sql = "update Registration_members set Description_self='$description', 
Disability='$disability' where Email='$email'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if($res)
{
?>
<script>
alert("You have registered successfully!!");
</script>
<?
echo $description." is description";
echo $disability." is disability";
}
}
?>
```

In output it writes

```
 is description
none is disability
```

Comment: Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. Also, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: @chintanmathukiya Don't edit out errors in the code. That's not a valid edit, and the errors you tried to fix are very likely the source of OP's problems here.

Comment: your code is fine... I have checked and create same code on my machine and value of textarea  is there.  use print_r($_POST); die; on php file

Comment: Where you are facing problem to save Data OR anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some edits to your code may solve your problem:

1) Always use `<?php`  as starting PHP tag. You have used only `<?` at one place in your code. Change that.

2) Change `isset($_REQUEST["submit"])` to `isset($_POST["submit"])`

3) Remove `type="textarea"` from your `<textarea>`

4) Be careful while opening and closing PHP tags. In your case, you have closed PHP tag just after `if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])) {` which is wrong.

Comment: made tag changes and tried all.. but still textarea value is not displayed ... radio button value is displayed but textarea shows empty value

Answer (score 0):

You are closing php tag too early.

Answer (score 0):

You need an opening `<?php` tag or your code will not be interpreted as PHP.

In the original version of your question, on your third line, you had `?>`. That closes the PHP block and means the next chunk of code is treated as plain HTML. So, it's never evaluated. Delete that line.

---

On that note, later in your code, you should use `<?php` , not `<?`, to start a new PHP code block.

Also, please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. On top of that, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: ya i have made changes in php closing still the problem is as it was.. It doesnt post textarea value.

Comment: I m currently working on localhost so i m using mysql for demo only

Comment: @leenapatel Are you sure? It should work now that you have fixed the PHP tag problem. Also, developing using a deprecated library just because you're on localhost is really bad practice.

Comment: @leenapatel please note that in your code as posted now, you don't have an opening `<?php` tag, which is just as bad as closing too early...

Comment: @leenapatel *What* tag changes have you made? Your PHP code as posted in your question either (1) is wrong for the reasons I have already pointed out or (2) is incomplete because it has no opening tag. It's impossible to help without seeing the actual code that is giving you problems.

Comment: @leenapatel First, that's not the real problem. You still don't have an opening `<?php` tag before the first line of PHP code. Second, it doesn't look like you made any edits; none showed up here. Seriously, please add the opening tag and see what happens. That's almost certainly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    <textarea id="description" type="textarea" name="description" rows="5" 
cols="40" class="textbox" form="register_form" required>type</textarea>
```

by

```
   <textarea id="description"  name="description" rows="5" 
cols="40" class="textbox" form="register_form" required></textarea>
```

type="textarea" is wrong, also use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST["submit"]`

Comment: yes i have made changes.. but sorry to say that dont work too.. i cant figure out the problem

Comment: @leenapatel it's running successfully on my machine..can you remove your css classes from textarea & check

Comment: <textarea  name="description" rows="5" cols="40" form="register_form" required></textarea>
I have done this changes but still the problem is same :(